# Cannot open signalr connection in silverlight client

Tags: c#, silverlight, signalr

I am trying to implement SignalR in Silverlight based on this blog: [SignalR and Silverlight](http://chris.59north.com/post/2011/12/15/SignalR-and-Silverlight.aspx).

When I try to .Invoke() I get a runtime error "System.InvalidOperationException: The Start method must be called before data can be sent.  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection.Send(String data) at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubProxy.Invoke[T](String method, Object[] args)..."

I have _conn.Start() on my connection.  If I try to Start() it a second time, right before invoke, it throws an exception.  Here is my code:

```
    private IHubProxy _hub;
    private HubConnection _conn;

    public AddProductView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var url = Application.Current.Host.Source.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme | UriComponents.HostAndPort,
                                                                UriFormat.Unescaped);
        _conn = new HubConnection(url);
        _hub = _conn.CreateHubProxy("SilverlightPrism.Mvc.Services.ProductHub");
        _hub.On<string>("NewMessage", message => Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => DoAddItem(message) ));
        _conn.Start();
    }

    private void DoAddItem(string item)
    {
        var product = DeserializeToProduct(item);
        ProductData.Products.Add(product);
    }

    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        var product = new Product
            {
                Price = random.Next(1000,100000),
                ProdId = id,
                ProdName = "New prod."
            };
        var jsonMessage = SerializeToJsonString(product);
        _hub.Invoke("SendMessage", jsonMessage);
    }
```

It is throwing the exception on _hub.Invoke();

How do I correctly get the hub connect and send a message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HubConnection.Start` is asynchronous. You cannot call `Start` right before `Invoke` because your `HubConnection` is probably still in the `Connecting` state.

You need to wait for the `Task` returned from `Start` to complete before you can call `IHubProxy.Invoke`. You can use `await` (or `Task.ContinueWith` if you aren't running .NET 4.5) to ensure `Start` finishes before you enable `buttonAdd`.

You could also create your `AddProductView` object asynchronously in a factory method. Instead of calling `HubConnection.Start` in the constructor, you could do it in a static `Task<AddProductView> CreateAddProductView()` method.

Alternatively, if you don't care about the creation of your `AddProductView` being asynchronous, you can just call `Start` synchronously:

```
_conn.Start().Wait();
```

Comment: Thanks, that moved me forward to seeing an error that I think was getting swallowed, server not found.  I should be in business once I fix the url.